# ImageMagick: why resized GIF image seems to have some colors replaced by white?

Tags: imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, gm

Was wondering if anyone knows what might be causing this.

Original image:

[image: img_20160206]

Thumbnail code (using http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/):

```
  const generateThumb = () => gm(this.getReadStream())
    .in('-thumbnail', '400x400^')
    .in('-gravity', 'center')
    .in('-extent', '400x400')
    .in('+profile', '*')
    .autoOrient()
    .stream()
```

Resulting image:

[image: waves-thumb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-background transparent` fixed the problem.

[image]